# Producing a Canvas output from NetworkX

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, networkx, sigma.js

The advantage of using matplotlib with NetworkX is the ease with which one can produce PDF, PNG, and SVG outputs.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G1 = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["a", "b"])
G.add_edge("a", "b")
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.savefig("graph.pdf")
plt.savefig("graph.png")
plt.savefig("graph.svg")
```

How can this code be modified to produce HTML5/Javascript Canvas code? Concrete code, however trivial, is more helpful than rooting for a given library. [Sigmajs](http://sigmajs.org/) seems promising, if not for the scanty documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to achieve what you want is to simply export the graph as [GEXF](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html) with Networkx using:

```
G = nx.path_graph(4)
nx.write_gexf(G, "test.gexf")
```

Then in your HTML you can use the sigma.js GEXF parser like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <style>
    #graph-container {
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
/**
 * The plugin sigma.parsers.gexf can load and parse the GEXF graph file,
 * and instantiate sigma when the graph is received.
 *
 * The object given as the second parameter is the base of the instance
 * configuration object. The plugin will just add the "graph" key to it
 * before the instanciation.
 */
sigma.parsers.gexf('data/arctic.gexf', { // path to graph here
  container: 'graph-container'
});
</script>
```

If you want to look at a real live example, I suggest [this blog post at the bottom](http://kirellbenzi.com/blog/exploring-the-star-wars-expanded-universe/).

DISCLAIMER: it's my blog ;)

Comment: I wrapped your code between '<html><head></head><body>' and
'</body></html>', preceded your `<script>` with '<script
src="sigma.min.js"></script>' and '<script
src="plugins/sigma.parsers.gexf.min.js"></script>', and replaced 'data/arctic.gexf' with 'test.gexf', but nothing
appears yet.

Comment: sigma.js should be hosted on your webserver or point to a minified version online.

Comment: Yes, I unpacked the sigma.js archive, placed 'sigma.min.js' and 'plugins/' in the same directory as the html file, and adjusted the references.

Comment: Check the permissions for the files, especially the graph.gexf (chmod 755)

Comment: Really? I'm serving all files locally (file://). In any case, that didn't help.

Comment: You need a webserver. You cannot execute JS to load a local file, it is by design. In a terminal, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` should do.

Comment: After 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000', the server confirms 'Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...'. Now rather than use the URL 'file:///path/to/file.html' I tried both 'h t t p ://localhost/path/to/file.html' and 'h t t p://localhost/file.html'—the latter on the assumption that the root of the server is the directory from which the  'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000' command was launched. Neither is successful. Another hint, please!

Comment: NetworkX gexf exporter does is not compatible out of the box with sigma.js – Or at least I haven't found a way to export it directly. You can review the structure of some other gexf files to see the differences.

Comment: the Force-directed graph is strong with this one